# Why does `({}+{}+{}*2).length` return 33 in Javascript?

Tags: javascript

In Javascript, `({}+{}).length` returns 30 whereas `({}+{}+{}*2).length` returns 33. I'm hoping for an accessible, pedagogical explanation of this behavior.

```js
const a = {}+{};
const b = {}+{}+{}*2;

console.log('({}+{}) =', a, a.length);
console.log('({}+{}+{}*2) =', b, b.length);
```

Comment: `{}+{}` returns `[object Object][object Object]` as string, add `.length` returns `30` since `"[object Object][object Object]".length` is 30.

Comment: See yourself in edited snippets.

Comment: `({}+{}+{}*2).length`, `{}+{}+{}` returns 45. But `{}*2` is `NaN` this gives us `{}+{}+{}*2` => `{}+{}+NaN` => `[object Object][object Object]NaN` which has a string length of `33`

Comment: [Wat](https://www.destroyallsoftware.com/talks/wat)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`+`, when either operand is not a number, will concatenate the string versions of both operands. So `{}+{}` will turn `{}` into a string on both sides, and concatenate them together. You get `[object Object]` concatenated with `[object Object]`, which is 30 characters long.

`+` operates left-to-right, and `*` has higher operator precedence. So

```
({}+{}+{}*2).length
```

is equivalent to:

```
({}+{}+{}*2).length
({}+{}+({}*2)).length
(({}+{})+({}*2)).length
(({}+{}                           )+({}*2)).length // same as above, but spaced out
(('[object Object][object Object]')+({}*2)).length
```

The `{} * 2` tries to multiply something which cannot be meaningfully converted to a number, so `NaN` is the result:

```
(('[object Object][object Object]')+({}*2)).length
(('[object Object][object Object]')+(NaN )).length
('[object Object][object Object]' + NaN).length
```

`+` will concatenate when either side is a string, so you get:

```
'[object Object][object Object]NaN'.length
```

which is 33.